# Laravel 8 Session not persisting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 8 app running on http://localhost:9003 under docker.
I'm having a bit of headache because sessions are not persisting between requests and I'm not sure why

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/session', function () {
    var_dump(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::all());
});

Route::get('/session-put', function () {
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::put('something', 'here');
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::save();
    var_dump(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::all());
});
```

Although it displays correctly under /session-put, navigating back to /session displays only the token **and creates a new file under /storage/framework/sessions**

In my Kernel I've added

```
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ...

    ];
```

And in my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=development
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=localhost
```

Deploying my app to a server seems to work, as in the /session I can see what has been put into /session-put

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Chrome then press F12 and check the "Cookies" section of the network request that gets the page. Make sure the cookie you receive after `session-put` is the same one sent to `session` (check to show filtered cookies if you can't see it in the list, it might give you an indication as to what's happening)

Comment: Every refresh generates a different cookie called `laravel_session`

Comment: Please, expand your `.env` file, you may have something wrong there with your `session`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if helpful to debug the problem, but once i open chrome with no security, it works.

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```